# Problems with UTF8 Characters in MySQL and Phalcon PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phalcon

I have a project in Phalcon PHP and MySql.

when UTF8 characters have to keep these errors are stored.

For example:
I save : nueva descripción ñññ
in Database: nueva descipciÃ³n Ã±Ã±Ã±

I have tried several types of collations both in the database, tables and fields.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Disagrees with duplicate flag as of none of said topic answers delivers solution for this issue.

Comment: @Andrés Luque have you check your mysql configuration?

Comment: any feedback? Is it working?

Comment: Search for Mojibake.

Answer (score 5):

While having properly defined database elements, you have to also set your connection to use UTF-8 ecoding. As of Phalcon makes use of PDO, you can try to modify your connection alike to:

```
$di["db"] = function() {
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        "host" => "localhost",
        "username" => "root",
        "password" => "1234",
        "dbname" => "test",
        "options" => array( // this is your important part
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
        )
    ));
};
```

Example from [Phalcon Forum](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/10/mysql-utf8-encoding).

As of I'm working with Polish language, my DB collations are mostly set to `utf8_polish_ci` or sometimes to `utf8_universal_ci`. You have to test it out because of result sorting issues.

Answer (score 0):

check your project database if it is **utf8-unicode-ci** collation.
*Also check all your individual table has collation utf-8-unicode-ci*

If it is not ok ,check your apache mysql config **my.ini** file

In that check UTF 8 Settings has no hash (#) comment like this

```
## UTF 8 Settings
init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'      //remove #
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci         
character_set_server=utf8
```